# Breeze not sending unmapped properties

Tags: angularjs, breeze

How do you get breeze to send client side only unmapped properties to the server? I've tried this as Ctor, initializer Es5 properties .. nothing gets sent to the server as far as these custom fields I'm trying to send along..

Answer (score 0):

So you have to mark the entityAspect modified (model.entityAspect.setModified())